# PLSQL error: Encountered the symbol when expecting: in procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, nested-table

I am new to PL/SQL, written a procedure and could not spot the error.
Implementation Details:
I am using few cursors to traverse through a table and store some relevant data in a nested table `(TYPE .. IS TABLE OF varchar(8))`.
Specifically, table prerequisites stores prereq courses of a given course. I have to find direct prereqs of a given course and the prereqs of the prereqs, if any.
Code:
precoll here is,

```
TYPE precoll IS TABLE of varchar2(8);
```

declared in the package, and procedure below is in package body. Procedure:

```
procedure disp_prereq(p_dept_code IN varchar2, p_courseno IN number, c_prereq OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
counter INTEGER ;
preserved INTEGER ;
prelist precoll := precoll();
row prerequisites%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
        counter := 1;
        preserved := 1;
    cursor cr is select * from prerequisites where dept_code = p_dept_code and course# = p_courseno;
        open cr;
        loop
                fetch cr into row;
                exit when row%notfound;
                prelist(counter) := (row.pre_dept_code || row.pre_course#) ;
                counter := counter + 1;
        end loop;
        close cr;
        preserved := prelist.count;
        preserved := preserved + 1;
        counter := 1;
        cursor indr is select * from prerequisites;
        open indr;
        loop
                fetch indr into row;
                exit when row%notfound;
                if (prelist(counter) = (m.dept_code||m.course#)) then
                        prelist(preserved) := m.pre_dept_code||m.pre_course# ;
                        preserved := preserved + 1;
                end if;
                counter := counter + 1;
        end loop;
        close indr;
        open c_prereq FOR select * from prelist;
END disp_prereq;
```

and show error gave me:

```
62/9     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CR" when expecting one of the
         following:
         := . ( @ % ;
```

And my second question,
prelist is a variable of precoll (TYPE precoll IS TABLE of varchar2(8);)
Can I query TYPE precoll by a select query, because it is a table of varchar?

Comment: Cursor `CR` declaration should be moved before `begin` keyword (in declaration section).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: The cursors should be declared in the declaration bart of the procedure. Move the:

```
cursor cr is select * from prerequisites where dept_code = p_dept_code and course# = p_courseno;
```

line to before the `BEGIN`. The same goes for the other cursor (indr). (There is also an alternative syntax where you declare a cursor variable in the declaration section and then use `OPEN cursor_variable FOR SELECT ...`.)

Question 2: Yes. In your case:

In the declare section:

```
prelist precoll;
cur cursor;
```

In the code section:

```
open cur for 
  SELECT * FROM table(prelist);
```

Here is another example from [Ask Tom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:603208800346416605).

Comment: Thanks, you precisely answered my queries, I'll try this.

Comment: The first problem is solved. But the second one, it is saying that the table 'prelist' is not found, no such table. What should I write in query, the type name or the variable name of that type?

Comment: Type name: precoll.
Variable name: prelist.

Comment: You need to tell the PL/SQL to "export" the table to SQL by writing `TABLE(prelist)`. I've added more text under Question 2 in my answer.